# How to set up two memcached server hosts in Joomla cache setting?

Tags: joomla, memcached, joomla3.0

I have set up two instances of memcached running on two servers. How do I set up the hosts in Joomla cache setting?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the configuration.php file at the site root folder and add the server details. Find the cache varibles **`$caching, $cache_handler, $memcache_server_host, $memcache_server_port.`**

Set them as follows

```
public $caching = '2';
public $cache_handler = 'memcache';
public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';//Give your memcache server address
public $memcache_server_port = '11111'; //Memcache server port
```

In the libraries/joomla/cache/storage/memcache.php file I found this lines

```
       /*
         * This will be an array of loveliness
         ***@todo: multiple servers***
         * $servers = (isset($params['servers'])) ? $params['servers'] : array();
         */
```

As you wanted to add two different memcache  servers, you can see that it is still under development. But there is a way ---By hacking core files.

**DONT TRY THE METHOD GIVEN BELOW IN PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT**

Though it is dangerous to play with core files but you can do at your own risk by following the method that I will suggest now. take backup first.

Take a backup of the files(configuration.php and libraries/joomla/cache/storage/memcache.php and libraries\vendor\joomla\session\Joomla\Session\Storage\Memcache.php). In the memcache file search for this code in the file

```
$server['host'] = $config->get('memcache_server_host', 'localhost');
        $server['port'] = $config->get('memcache_server_port', 11211);

        // Create the memcache connection
        self::$_db = new Memcache;
        self::$_db->addServer($server['host'], $server['port'], $this->_persistent);

        $memcachetest = @self::$_db->connect($server['host'], $server['port']);

        if ($memcachetest == false)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Could not connect to memcache server', 404);
        }
```

Add this code below

```
    //Give second server details like this
$server['host2'] = $config->get('memcache_server_host2', 'localhost');
$server['port2'] = $config->get('memcache_server_port2', 11211);
    // Create the memcache connection
            self::$_db = new Memcache;
            self::$_db->addServer($server['host2'], $server['port2'], $this->_persistent);

            $memcachetest = @self::$_db->connect($server['host2'], $server['port2']);

            if ($memcachetest == false)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException('Could not connect to memcache server', 404);
            }
```

In the configuration.php file add this lines

```
public $memcache_server_host2 = 'localhost';//Give your second memcache server address
public $memcache_server_port2 = '11111'; //Memcache second server port
```

Now for storing sessions you have to edit files that stores session cache

In the file libraries\vendor\joomla\session\Joomla\Session\Storage\Memcache.php you will find these line

```
$this->_servers = array(
            array(
                'host' => isset($options['memcache_server_host']) ? $options['memcache_server_host'] : 'localhost',
                'port' => isset($options['memcache_server_port']) ? $options['memcache_server_port'] : 11211
            )
        );
```

Change this to

```
$this->_servers = array(
            array(
                'host' => isset($options['memcache_server_host']) ? $options['memcache_server_host'] : 'localhost',
                'port' => isset($options['memcache_server_port']) ? $options['memcache_server_port'] : 11211
            ),
array(
                'host2' => isset($options['memcache_server_host2']) ? $options['memcache_server_host2'] : 'localhost',
                'port2' => isset($options['memcache_server_port2']) ? $options['memcache_server_port2'] : 11211
            )
        );
```

Comment: I have two memcache server. How do I define another host and port?

Comment: @James I have given some alternate solution. Hope this works.

Comment: thanks. Seems like I need to wait for the production ready code from Joomla since I need to use it for production environment.